# IF we weaken comprehension of second order logic to first order formulas, would the resulting system be a conservative extension of FOL?

Tags: lo.logic

Take [second order logic](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/logic-higher-order/), weaken the [comprehension axiom schemata](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/logic-higher-order/#AxioSecoOrdeLogi) to using only FIRST order formulas; that is, $\phi(x_1,..,x_n)$ in the referred article is restricted to be a first order formula. Keep all the other aspects of second order logic.

> Now would the resulting system be a kind of a conservative extension of first order logic? That is, a logic that allows quantification over relation and function symbols, yet not having axioms extra to those of first order logic, and so enjoys the merits of first order logic.

> Can we always add a first order theory, but write its schemas as SINGLE axioms in that logic? So for example separation schema in Zermelo would be written as a single axiom by quantifying over predicates, as: $$\forall P \forall A \exists X \forall y (y \in X \leftrightarrow y \in A \land P(y))$$

I had asked a similar question on MathStackExchange, and I received no answer?

Comment: Could you state the list of axioms of your second-order logic? For example, does it contain the axiom of choice $\forall x\exists y R(x,y)\to \exists f \forall x R(x,f(x))$?

Comment: @HanulJeon, well I didn't include those choice axioms. The axioms are those of propositional logic and first order logic. however the comprehension axioms of second order logic are weakened as presented above. The language allows quantification over relation and function symbols, all the formation rules of second order logic, distribution, substitution and inference rules are there. No choice axioms.

Comment: Let $\varphi$ be a first-order formula which is proved in your system. Let $M$ be a first-order structure (adapted to the appropriate first-order language). It is enough to show that $M$ satisfies $\varphi$.

Add to $M$ all first-order definable relations, obtaining $M^*$. All axioms and rules of your weakened second-order system are valid in $M^*$, so $M^*$ satisfies $\varphi$. Hence $M$ satisfies $\varphi$.

Comment: This proves that it is conservative (I have restricted myself to the case in which only relation sysmbols are allowed), or maybe I have not understood the question. Is there anything wrong with the above argument?

Comment: @RodrigoFreire, my point was that we no longer can define first order predicates (i.e. predicates whose arguments are objects) after second order formulas. So there are not new first order predicates, so all first order predicates are those of the first order sector of that language. The idea is if the resulting theory retains the merits of FOL also? That is, has a proof system, compact, etc..

Comment: I have not understood your last comment, specially the end of it. Your first comment makes reference to axioms and inference rules, therefore I have concluded that you were presenting your second-order logic  proof-theoretically. Now you ask if your logic has a proof system. What is your second-order consequence relation? That is not clear.

Comment: @RodrigoFreire, I spoke about my intentions behind having such logic. A logic that retains the merits of first order logic regarding provability, compactness, etc.., but at the same time can quantify over relation and function symbols. I don't know what you mean by second-order consequence relation here, can you give me examples of that in the ordinary second-order logic, do you mean the definition of a proof? I'd say its the same as in first order logic after Hilbert's.

Comment: If your system S is an axiomatic Hilbert calculus with the axioms and rules you have mentioned, then my first comment gives a conservativity proof over first-order logic. If it is anything wrong with that proof, if it does not apply to the system S you have in mind, then you should say exactly why it fails.

Comment: @RodrigoFreire, well thanks for the comment. But why you didn't post it as an answer?

Comment: Because I was not sure about the question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Preliminary remark: after some clarification in the comments, I am posting my comment as an answer.

Let $\varphi$ be a first-order formula which is proved in your Hilbert style system $S$. Let $M$ be a first-order structure (adapted to the appropriate first-order language). From the completeness of first-order logic, it is enough to show that $M$ satisfies $\varphi$. Add to $M$ all first-order definable relations and functions, obtaining $M^∗$. All axioms and rules of your weakened second-order system $S$ are valid in $M^∗$ (Henkin semantics), so $M^∗$ satisfies $\varphi$ by soundness. Since $M$ is a reduct of $M^*$ and is adapted to the language of $\varphi$, $M$ satisfies $\varphi$.